# Project as nested document in spring mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm looking for a translator to change this :

```
getCollection('migrate').aggregate([  
{ "$project": {  
"Contrat": {"Field1":"$Field1", "Field2":"$Field2"},
"Formule": {"Field3":"$Field3", "Field4":"$Field4"}  
    }},  
    { "$project": {  
      "Contrats": {"Contrat":"$Contrat", "Formule":"$Formule"}  
    }}  
])
```

to MongoJava aggregation framework. Something like :

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("Field1,Field2");  // while naming it "Contrat"
AggregationOperation project2 = Aggregation.project("Field3,Fiel4");  // while naming it Formule
AggregationOperation project3 = Aggregation.project("Contrat,Formule");   // while naming it " Contrats"

AggregationOperation out = Aggregation.out("test");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, project2, project3, out);

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "<nameOfInitialCollection>", Class.class);
```

I can't find my answers in the documentation, which I think is too poor, or I may be too lost in it ( | dumb).

I'll thank you in advance.

Comment: Or at least i'm trying to conserv my mongoDB query and execute it with :
mongoTemplate.executeCommand() but i can't find the proper way to make it work. Always getting error on the JSON parse value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().
         and("Contrat").nested(Fields.fields("Field1","Field2")).
         and("Formule").nested(Fields.fields("Field3","Field4"));
AggregationOperation project2 = Aggregation.project().
         and("Contrats").nested(Fields.fields("Contrat","Formule")).
AggregationOperation out = Aggregation.out("test");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, project2, out);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "<nameOfInitialCollection>", Class.class);
```

Comment: You're my superman Veeram
Unfortunatly i can't test it today. I'll accept the anwser as soon as it is tested. 

On the other hand, what about if i want to use mongoTemplate.executeCommand ? 
My problem is on another matter, i'm trying to aggregate two collection having more than 2M lines, this pipeline works perfectly but java return Memory error
I think it is trying to instantiate the result of an aggregation before passing the garbage collector on it, even tho i don't display the result. 
So i'm looking to skip the execution via Java and send directly to mongo the JSON script